# Installing PowerShell on 32-bit Kali OS fails

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, 32bit, powershell

I am having some issues installing PowerShell on my 32-bit Kali Linux PC. 
I followed [this guide](https://www.kali.org/tutorials/installing-powershell-on-kali-linux/) and started with:

```
apt update && apt -y install curl gnupg apt-transport-https
```

Next, I downloaded and added the public repository GPG key so APT will trust the packages and alert the user to any issues with package signatures.

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
```

With the GPG key added, I added the Microsoft package repository to its own package list file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and updated the list of available packages.

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod stretch main" \
                                                > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/powershell.list
apt update
```

No errors so far indicated in the update process, Microsoft sources are in my source.list, and everything should be good to go.

When I execute:

```
apt -y install powershell
```

I get:

```
root@kali:/opt# apt -y install powershell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package powershell
```

Comment: what does `apt-cache search powershell` show you?

Comment: browsing that repo, I see "powershell" listed; do you have an amd64 system? (`uname -m`)

Comment: @TimKennedy

Here is my output:

    root@kali:~# apt-cache search powershell
    crackmapexec - Swiss army knife for pentesting networks
    nishang - Collection of PowerShell scripts and payloads
    powersploit - PowerShell Post-Exploitation Framework
    python-dcos - Datacenter Operating System (DCOS) CLI - Python 2.7
    python3-dcos - DCOS Common Modules - Python 3.x
    python3-winrm - Python 3 library for Windows Remote Management
    unicorn-magic - Tool for a PowerShell downgrade attack and inject shellcode

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm i686.

Comment: @WeAreOne, it does not seem that Microsoft [supports powershell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) for 32-bit architecture on Linux.

Comment: @kemotep See also, https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4707 and https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7659 -- looks like it depends on .NET Core too

Comment: @WeAreOne what CPU do you have? If it is 64-bit-capable, you could install a 64-bit kernel in your 32-bit Kali installation and install the 64-bit PowerShell package using multiarch.

Comment: the only 32-bit Linux powershell being supported is [ARM Raspbian](https://github.com/powershell/powershell). Why do you use a 32-bit OS nowadays? Almost all x86 CPUs you can buy in the last 2 decades are 64-bit capable

Answer (score 14):

You have successfully added the repository for Powershell to your `sources.list`.

However, you report to be using a 32-bit architecture system. Your output of `apt-cache` confirms that your Repositories do not contain the Powershell package.

Taking a look at the [Powershell GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell), it appears that Microsoft does not provide a Linux package for Powershell for 32-bit Linux systems. All of the source and binary packages available for Linux here are for 64-bit systems.

As user Bob points out in his comment, Powershell for Linux depends on [.Net Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7659).

If you are familiar with building from source, you could potentially build a 32-bit package, but that is a different kind of question. This may not actually work as Powershell maybe has hard requirements for 64-bit instructions and optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve added the PowerShell repository, but it only provides `amd64` binaries (as indicated by the architecture qualifier Microsoft tell you to include). You can’t run the binaries on your 32-bit system... That is, unless your CPU supports 64-bit mode (which you can check by looking for `lm` in the processor flags in `/proc/cpuinfo`) and you configure your system appropriately.

(If you’re running a live Kali system, you might as well reboot into a 64-bit Kali setup instead.)

The following instructions aren’t Kali-specific, they will work on any Debian derivative.

To add 64-bit support:

- enable `amd64`:

  ```
  dpkg --add-architecture amd64
  ```
- ensure your system is up-to-date:

  ```
  apt update && apt upgade
  ```
- install the appropriate kernel (this will vary, depending on the installed distribution and the currently-valid kernel; run `uname -r` to get an idea of the package name to use):

  ```
  apt install linux-image-4.19.0-kali4-amd64
  ```
- reboot, and in the advanced options in the Grub menu, choose the `amd64` kernel
- since Microsoft’s PowerShell repository is based on Debian 9, you may need to add the corresponding repository (this isn’t typically recommended in Kali setups, but [Kali themselves document it](https://www.kali.org/tutorials/advanced-package-management-in-kali-linux/), so...):

  ```
  echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch.list
  ```

  (this is now necessary on Kali because the `libicu57` package is no longer available there, so you’d have to do this even if you were following [the Kali PowerShell installation guide](https://www.kali.org/tutorials/installing-powershell-on-kali-linux/))
- update again and install PowerShell:

  ```
  apt update && apt install powershell
  ```

Now you’ll still be running a mostly 32-bit install, but with the ability to install 64-bit packages where necessary.

Comment: Next level help in that answer.  Thank you!